# With many-to-many relationship, associated class data cannot be fetched with find method in doctrine and symfony2

Tags: doctrine, symfony, many-to-many

I am using doctrine with symfony2 framework. I have an entity 'Question' which can have multiple 'Theme's. So I defined this many-to-may relationship (also on the other hand Themes can have multiple Questions) in yml:

```
  manyToMany:
    themes:
      targetEntity: Theme
      joinTable:
        name: question_themes
        joinColumns:
          question_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          theme_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

And inside the Question entity class:

```
private $themes;
public function setThemes($themes) {
    $this->themes = $themes;
}
public function getThemes() {
    return $this->themes;
}
```

Here, question_themes is a table(in MySQL) which holds the many-to-many relationship i.e.  question_id and theme_id.

Now when I fetch question data by:

```
$questions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->findAll();
```

or

```
$questions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->findBy(
                array('locale'=>$locale),
                array('createdAt' => 'DESC')
            );
```

etc. it fetches all the associated themes data along with questions i.e.

```
foreach($questions as $question) {
    foreach($question->getThemes() as $theme) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Everything seems perfect. But whenever I fetch the question data by:

```
$question = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->find($question_id);
```

or

```
$question = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->findById($question_id);
```

etc, then the associated theme data are not being fetched and thus I am getting error at the foreach loop:

```
foreach($question->getThemes() as $theme) {
    // some code
}
```

Can anybody help on this, as I am new to doctrine and symfony2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your entity setter a little. Instead of using setThemes (or setQuestions in the theme entity) I would use an "add" function because it is an array();

Also I put the annotation reference in there just in case.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Path\To\Entity\Theme", mappedBy="questions")
 */
private $themes;

public function addTheme(Theme $theme)
{
    $this->themes[] = $theme;
}

public function getThemes()
{
    return $this->themes;
}
```

Also make this change in the Theme entity (but with the annotation as inversedBy instead of mappedBy). Update your schema and give it a try.

Comment: I am using yml instead of annotation, so defined the schema like so as in the quesion. I changed the entity getter-setter accordingly but it didn't solve my problem. However according to your schema definition, where can I specify the question_themes table, which contains the many-to-many relationship?

Comment: With annotations based on the code I provided the question_themes table would be automatically generated after calling doctrine:schema:update --force See: http://tracehello.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/symfony2-doctrine2-manytomany-association/ As for using yml, to be honest I have only used it in one of my projects and didn't have a manytomany relationship.